# wpf checked list box question

Tags: wpf, checkedlistbox

I am creating checked list box with the following template:

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxListStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
            <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Multiple"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" >
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=xxxxxxxxxxx,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Mode=TwoWay}">                                                                             <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                                    </CheckBox>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

 <ListBox Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxListStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Configuration.ProductTypes}" DisplayMemberPath="ProductName" />
```

my problem is, i am getting all the product types from Database and binding it to the list box itemssource. i have a product class which contains a list of product types it belongs to. i need to set the IsChecked property of check boxes based on Product's product type list. Typically i need to set one or more check  boxes IsChecked property.  product may belong to 1 or more product types. and selection mode is multiselect. if user checks the additional product type check boxes ..i need to get the total checked list boxes and save them to the database... this is a MVVM WPF application ...    any ideas on how to solve this scenario...
in the controltemplate what will be the path is IsChecked?

Thanks
Rey

Let me simplyfy my question: I need a list box with checkbox and textblock. textblock data context is different and check box data context is different. i mean they get their data from different objects. no idea how to achieve this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let me simplyfy my question: I need a
>   list box with checkbox and textblock.
>   textblock data context is different
>   and check box data context is
>   different. i mean they get their data
>   from different objects. no idea how to
>   achieve this...

Create a new class (a ViewModel) which contains the two data contexts (Model1 and Model2) and data bind to it, also known as the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The ProductType class that you're binding to the ListBox should have a read/write property called IsSelected or IsChecked that you can bind to. Then instead of using a ControlTemplate, use a DataTemplate on the ListBox.ItemTemplate and bind the CheckBox's IsChecked property to that property.

Comment: ProductType contain all the possible product types from the database. based on a product Id i will get a product Object from DB, which contain a sub list of product types it belong to. there is no isselected or ischecked property. i will have a productname and id. i will look into datatemplate thing.. thanks ...